# My app crashes when i go in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I have one fragment displaying in an activity when it is in portrait mode. The fragment contains a ListView. When an item is clicked, it opens up another activity which has another fragment that contains detail about the listView item clicked. Now when its in landscape, it is suppose to show the first Fragment(ListView) and next to it, the second Fragment(detail about the item selected from the ListView). But it is crashing. The error in my logcat is nullpointerexception. Any help would be appreciated.

My GradeListActivity.java:

```
public class GradeListActivity extends Activity
{
    public GradeCollection gc = new GradeCollection();    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grade_list_activity);
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            //ListViewFragment LVF = new ListViewFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.ui_container, new ListViewFragment());
            //GradeDetailFragment GDF = new GradeDetailFragment();
            int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                ft.add(R.id.ui_detail, new GradeDetailFragment());
            }
            ft.commit();
    }
}
```

my grade_list_activity.xml(landscape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ui_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

my grade_list_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

My GradeListFragment.java:

```
     public class GradeDetailFragment extends Fragment {

        public GradeCollection gc = new GradeCollection();
        public int position;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(   LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {   
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grade_detail_fargment, container, false);

            Activity a = getActivity();
            Intent i = a.getIntent();

            gc = (GradeCollection) i.getExtras().getSerializable("OriginalGradeCollectionInstance");
            position = (Integer) i.getExtras().getSerializable("position");


            EditText textCategory = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextCategory);
            EditText textNumber = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
            EditText textGrade = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextGrade);
            EditText textDescription = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);


//This code chunk might be giving me NPE
            //if(gc != null)
            //{
                textCategory.setText(gc.GetItem(position).getCategory() + "");
                textNumber.setText(gc.GetItem(position).getNumber() + "");
                String grade = "" + gc.GetItem(position).getGrade();
                textGrade.setText(grade);
                textDescription.setText(gc.GetItem(position).getDescription() + "");
            //}
            return v;
        }
    }
```

And my LogCat:

```
 04-14 03:02:11.565: D/AndroidRuntime(3598): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-14 03:02:11.565: D/AndroidRuntime(3598): CheckJNI is ON
04-14 03:02:11.595: D/dalvikvm(3598): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:11.605: D/dalvikvm(3598): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:11.635: D/dalvikvm(3598): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:11.635: D/dalvikvm(3598): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:12.315: D/AndroidRuntime(3598): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-14 03:02:12.365: W/ActivityManager(2382): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.apk
04-14 03:02:12.465: W/ActivityManager(2382): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.apk
04-14 03:02:12.465: I/PackageManager(2382): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1175232448
04-14 03:02:12.665: I/PackageManager(2382): Removing non-system package:bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation
04-14 03:02:12.675: I/ActivityManager(2382): Force stopping package bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation appid=10048 user=-1
04-14 03:02:12.675: I/ActivityManager(2382): Killing proc 3543:bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/u0a10048: force stop bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation
04-14 03:02:12.675: I/ActivityManager(2382):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{40ed9828 u0 bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.MainActivity}
04-14 03:02:12.705: I/WindowState(2382): WIN DEATH: Window{4110b3d0 u0 bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.MainActivity}
04-14 03:02:12.805: I/PackageManager(2382): Package bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation codePath changed from /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-1.apk to /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
04-14 03:02:12.815: I/PackageManager(2382): Running dexopt on: bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation
04-14 03:02:13.735: I/dalvikvm(3609): DexOpt: access denied from Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatKitKat; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.actions
04-14 03:02:14.395: D/dalvikvm(3609): DexOpt: load 252ms, verify+opt 828ms, 1242628 bytes
04-14 03:02:14.485: I/ActivityManager(2382): Force stopping package bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation appid=10048 user=-1
04-14 03:02:14.485: W/PackageManager(2382): Code path for pkg : bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation changing from /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-1.apk to /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-2.apk
04-14 03:02:14.485: W/PackageManager(2382): Resource path for pkg : bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation changing from /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-1.apk to /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-2.apk
04-14 03:02:14.565: D/PackageManager(2382): New package installed in /data/app/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation-2.apk
04-14 03:02:14.655: I/ActivityManager(2382): Force stopping package bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation appid=10048 user=0
04-14 03:02:14.785: I/InputReader(2382): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
04-14 03:02:14.805: W/ContextImpl(2873): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2376 
04-14 03:02:15.046: I/InputReader(2382): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
04-14 03:02:15.205: W/InputMethodManagerService(2382): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
04-14 03:02:15.545: D/dalvikvm(2382): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1115K, 24% free 7369K/9668K, paused 18ms+33ms, total 232ms
04-14 03:02:15.575: D/AndroidRuntime(3598): Shutting down VM
04-14 03:02:15.585: D/dalvikvm(3598): GC_CONCURRENT freed 94K, 18% free 467K/564K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 11ms
04-14 03:02:15.585: D/jdwp(3598): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
04-14 03:02:15.585: D/dalvikvm(3598): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-14 03:02:15.835: W/RecognitionManagerService(2382): no available voice recognition services found for user 0
04-14 03:02:16.285: D/AndroidRuntime(3617): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-14 03:02:16.285: D/AndroidRuntime(3617): CheckJNI is ON
04-14 03:02:16.345: D/dalvikvm(3617): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:16.366: D/dalvikvm(3617): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:16.455: D/dalvikvm(3617): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:16.455: D/dalvikvm(3617): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-14 03:02:17.215: D/AndroidRuntime(3617): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-14 03:02:17.225: D/dalvikvm(3617): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 157 unimplemented (abstract) methods
04-14 03:02:17.245: I/ActivityManager(2382): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.MainActivity} from pid 3617
04-14 03:02:17.335: D/AndroidRuntime(3617): Shutting down VM
04-14 03:02:17.345: D/dalvikvm(3627): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-14 03:02:17.355: D/dalvikvm(3617): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 17% free 499K/600K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 10ms
04-14 03:02:17.355: D/jdwp(3617): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
04-14 03:02:17.355: D/dalvikvm(3617): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-14 03:02:17.385: I/ActivityManager(2382): Start proc bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation for activity bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.MainActivity: pid=3627 uid=10048 gids={50048, 1028}
04-14 03:02:17.625: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-14 03:02:17.765: E/Trace(3627): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-14 03:02:18.405: D/dalvikvm(3627): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 7% free 2710K/2904K, paused 12ms+26ms, total 103ms
04-14 03:02:18.445: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-14 03:02:18.465: D/libEGL(3627): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-14 03:02:18.465: D/(3627): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a165848, tid 3627
04-14 03:02:18.476: D/libEGL(3627): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-14 03:02:18.485: D/libEGL(3627): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-14 03:02:18.525: W/EGL_emulation(3627): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-14 03:02:18.535: D/OpenGLRenderer(3627): Enabling debug mode 0
04-14 03:02:18.735: I/ActivityManager(2382): Displayed bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.MainActivity: +1s411ms
04-14 03:02:21.175: I/ActivityManager(2382): START u0 {cmp=bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.GradeListActivity (has extras)} from pid 3627
04-14 03:02:21.405: D/dalvikvm(3627): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 88K, 7% free 2846K/3056K, paused 36ms, total 37ms
04-14 03:02:21.405: I/dalvikvm-heap(3627): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.501MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-14 03:02:21.475: D/dalvikvm(3627): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 3466K/3680K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
04-14 03:02:21.535: D/dalvikvm(3627): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 6% free 3475K/3680K, paused 6ms+23ms, total 64ms
04-14 03:02:21.705: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-14 03:02:21.725: W/EGL_emulation(3627): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-14 03:02:21.955: I/ActivityManager(2382): Displayed bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.GradeListActivity: +737ms
04-14 03:02:24.255: I/InputReader(2382): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
04-14 03:02:24.255: I/InputReader(2382): Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 480x800, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
04-14 03:02:24.265: I/ActivityManager(2382): Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w491dp h294dp 240dpi nrml land finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.15}
04-14 03:02:24.565: D/dalvikvm(2947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8933K, 65% free 4966K/14064K, paused 100ms, total 105ms
04-14 03:02:24.585: I/dalvikvm-heap(2947): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.078MB for 6410576-byte allocation
04-14 03:02:24.695: D/dalvikvm(2947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 260K, 23% free 10965K/14064K, paused 109ms, total 110ms
04-14 03:02:24.922: D/dalvikvm(3627): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 5% free 3683K/3840K, paused 152ms, total 199ms
04-14 03:02:24.945: I/dalvikvm-heap(3627): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.319MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-14 03:02:25.005: D/dalvikvm(2947): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 23% free 10966K/14064K, paused 5ms+154ms, total 313ms
04-14 03:02:25.085: D/dalvikvm(3627): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 4% free 4296K/4464K, paused 79ms+5ms, total 143ms
04-14 03:02:25.085: D/dalvikvm(3627): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 64ms
04-14 03:02:25.556: D/AndroidRuntime(3627): Shutting down VM
04-14 03:02:25.556: W/dalvikvm(3627): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.GradeListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.GradeDetailFragment.onCreateView(GradeDetailFragment.java:30)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
04-14 03:02:25.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3627):     ... 12 more
04-14 03:02:25.655: W/ActivityManager(2382):   Force finishing activity bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.GradeListActivity
04-14 03:02:25.725: D/dalvikvm(2947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 23% free 10966K/14064K, paused 150ms, total 150ms
04-14 03:02:25.745: I/dalvikvm-heap(2947): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.309MB for 2606048-byte allocation
04-14 03:02:25.835: D/dalvikvm(2947): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 13511K/14064K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 96ms
04-14 03:02:25.835: D/dalvikvm(2947): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 89ms
04-14 03:02:25.965: D/dalvikvm(2382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 687K, 23% free 7523K/9668K, paused 239ms, total 250ms
04-14 03:02:25.975: I/dalvikvm-heap(2382): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.074MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-14 03:02:26.075: D/dalvikvm(2382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 22% free 8124K/10292K, paused 96ms, total 96ms
04-14 03:02:26.195: W/WindowManager(2382): Window freeze timeout expired.
04-14 03:02:26.195: W/WindowManager(2382): Force clearing orientation change: Window{4108cac8 u0 NavigationBar}
04-14 03:02:26.195: W/WindowManager(2382): Force clearing orientation change: Window{40ec49f0 u0 StatusBar}
04-14 03:02:26.195: W/WindowManager(2382): Force clearing orientation change: Window{412dab18 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper}
04-14 03:02:26.475: W/ActivityManager(2382): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40f38d20 u0 bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.GradeListActivity}
04-14 03:02:26.715: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-14 03:02:26.725: I/Choreographer(2947): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-14 03:02:27.845: I/Process(3627): Sending signal. PID: 3627 SIG: 9
04-14 03:02:27.865: I/WindowState(2382): WIN DEATH: Window{40f5adc8 u0 bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.MainActivity}
04-14 03:02:27.865: I/ActivityManager(2382): Process bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation (pid 3627) has died.
04-14 03:02:27.905: D/dalvikvm(3643): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-14 03:02:27.935: I/ActivityManager(2382): Start proc bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation for activity bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.MainActivity: pid=3643 uid=10048 gids={50048, 1028}
04-14 03:02:28.246: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-14 03:02:28.285: E/Trace(3643): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-14 03:02:28.945: D/dalvikvm(3643): GC_CONCURRENT freed 78K, 7% free 2710K/2908K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 83ms
04-14 03:02:28.995: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-14 03:02:29.015: D/libEGL(3643): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-14 03:02:29.015: D/(3643): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a154410, tid 3643
04-14 03:02:29.025: D/libEGL(3643): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-14 03:02:29.035: D/libEGL(3643): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-14 03:02:29.075: W/EGL_emulation(3643): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-14 03:02:29.085: D/OpenGLRenderer(3643): Enabling debug mode 0
04-14 03:02:29.115: W/InputMethodManagerService(2382): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 3627 uid 10048
04-14 03:02:29.305: I/ActivityManager(2382): Displayed bcs421.muhammadqumail.hwk.gradeapp.presentation/.MainActivity: +1s422ms
04-14 03:02:30.685: D/dalvikvm(2382): GC_EXPLICIT freed 256K, 21% free 8172K/10292K, paused 13ms+12ms, total 135ms
04-14 03:02:38.185: D/ExchangeService(2762): Received deviceId from Email app: null
04-14 03:02:38.185: D/ExchangeService(2762): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
04-14 03:02:43.235: D/ExchangeService(2762): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
04-14 03:02:43.255: W/ActivityManager(2382): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
04-14 03:02:43.255: D/ExchangeService(2762): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
04-14 03:02:43.265: W/ActivityManager(2382): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d41668 that was originally bound here
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d41668 that was originally bound here
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762): null
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d41668 that was originally bound here
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-14 03:02:43.285: E/StrictMode(2762):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-14 03:02:43.295: W/ActivityManager(2382): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41165ea0
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce7880 that was originally bound here
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce7880 that was originally bound here
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-14 03:02:43.315: E/ActivityThread(2762):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
```

Comment: The stacktrace leads to your `GradeDetailFragment`, posting its `onCreateView()` code would help.

Comment: which code line is Line 30 in logcat? please write comment `// Line 30` right after the code line.

Comment: Can you update us whether you're still facing the issue or not?

Comment: The issue is still there, i will get to work on it over the weekend. Once i have any more updates, i will get back to you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Upon an orientation change, Android recreates an activity but it doesn't pass again the *intent* that originally started the activity. So when you rotate the screen, `getIntent()` returns `null` and the code that follows then throws a `NullPointerException`.

So to fix your issue, you need to initialize your fragment from the *intent* data only when it's being created afresh which you can determine by checking if `savedInstanceState` is `null`.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    Intent i = a.getIntent();
    gc = (GradeCollection) i.getExtras()
                            .getSerializable("OriginalGradeCollectionInstance");
    position = (Integer) i.getExtras().getSerializable("position");
}
```

But, this means that post-rotation your *fragment* doesn't initialize itself correctly with the *intent* data it received before. So, to make this happen you need to save your `GradeCollection` and `position` to the instance state *bundle* just before Android destroys your *fragment*.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", position);
    outState.putSerializable("grades", gc);
}
```

Then simply restore *fragment* state in `onCreateView()` as

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    Intent i = a.getIntent();
    gc = (GradeCollection) i.getExtras()
                            .getSerializable("OriginalGradeCollectionInstance");
    position = (Integer) i.getExtras().getSerializable("position");
} else {
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
    gc = (GradeCollection) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("grades");
}
```

Please note that you would need to make your `GradeCollection` (and any non-wrapper custom members' class) implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is not normally available to a fragment in `onCreateView()`. Try some moving:

```java
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        Intent i = activity.getIntent();

        gc = (GradeCollection) i.getExtras().getSerializable("OriginalGradeCollectionInstance");
        position = (Integer) i.getExtras().getSerializable("position");

        textCategory.setText(gc.GetItem(position).getCategory() + "");
        textNumber.setText(gc.GetItem(position).getNumber() + "");
        String grade = "" + gc.GetItem(position).getGrade();
        textGrade.setText(grade);
        textDescription.setText(gc.GetItem(position).getDescription() + "");
    }
```

Delete corresponding lines in `onCreateView()` and also make all `EditText`s - the fragment's fields.

Comment: I did what you ask me todo and it is still giving me a nullpointer exception. The reason i think is because when its in landscape mode, the second fragment(detail of each item in listview) is empty. It gets filled when an item is clicked of the list

Comment: @MuhammadQumail ok, then please point us to a specific line as per the stacktrace that produces the NPE

Comment: I just updated the GradeListFragment. java and added a comment where i think it is causing me NPE. btw i also checked for not null and it still gave me error, that is why i commented the if statement

Comment: @MuhammadQumail thanks, but still which exact line in `GradeListFragment.java` is line #30? So that we don't have to take wild guesses any more :)

Comment: position = (Integer) i.getExtras().getSerializable("position");//line 30